# delete entries at certain indices in space delimited text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, while-loop, sh

I have a .txt file with numeric indices of certain 'outlier' data points, each on their own line, called by $outlier_file:

```
1 
7 
30 
43 
48 
49 
56 
57 
65
```

Using the following code, I can successfully remove certain files (volumes of neuroimaging data in this case) by using while + read.

```
while read outlier; do
    # Remove current outlier vol from eddy unwarped DWI data
    rm $DWI_path/$1/vol000*"$outlier".nii.gz;
done < $outlier_file
```

However, I also need to remove the numbers located at these 'outlier' indices from another text file stored in $bvec_file, which has 69 columns & 3 rows. Within each row, the numbers are space delimited. So e.g., for this example, I need to remove all 3 rows of column 1, 7, 30, etc. and then save this version with the outliers removed into a new *.txt file.

```
0  0.9988864166  -0.0415925034  -0.06652866169  -0.6187155495  0.2291534462  0.8892356214  0.7797364286  0.1957395685  0.9236669465  -0.5400265342  -0.3845263463  -0.4903989539  0.4863306385  -0.6496130843  0.5571164636  0.8110081715  0.9032142094  -0.3234596075  -0.1551409525  -0.806059879  0.4811597826  -0.7820757748  -0.9528881463  0.1916556621  -0.007136403284  -0.2459431735  -0.7915263574  -0.1938049261  -0.1578786349  0.8688043633  -0.5546072294  -0.4019951732  0.2806154851  0.3478762022  0.9548067252  -0.9696777541  -0.4816255837  -0.7962240023  0.6818610905  0.7097978218  0.6739686799  0.1317547111  -0.7648252249  -0.1456021218  -0.5948047487  0.0934205064  0.5268769564  -0.8618324858  -0.3721029232  -0.1827616535  0.691353613  0.4159071597  0.4605505287  0.1312199424  0.426674893  -0.4068291509  0.7167859082  0.2330824665  0.01909161256  -0.06375254731  -0.5981122948  -0.2672253674  0.6875472994  0.2302943724  0  0  0  0  
0  0.04258194557  0.9988207007  0.6287131425  0.7469024143  0.5528476637  0.3024964957  0.1446931241  0.9305823612  0.1675139932  0.8208211337  0.8238722992  0.5983722761  0.4238174961  0.639429196  0.1072148887  0.5551578885  0.003337599176  0.511740508  0.9516619405  0.3851404227  0.8526321065  0.1390947346  0.2030449535  0.7759459569  0.165587903  0.9523372297  0.5801228933  0.3277276562  0.7413928896  0.442482978  0.2320585706  0.1079269171  0.1868672655  0.1606136006  0.2968573235  0.1682337977  0.8745679247  0.5989061899  0.4172933119  0.01746934331  0.5641480832  0.7455469091  0.3471016571  0.8035001467  0.5870623128  0.361107261  0.8192579877  0.4160218909  0.5651330299  0.4070513153  0.7221181184  0.714223583  0.6971767133  0.4937978446  0.4232911691  0.8011701162  0.2870385494  0.9016941521  0.09688949547  0.9086826131  0.2631932421  0.152678096  0.6295753848  0.9712458578  0  0  0  0  
0  -0.02031513434  -0.02504539005  -0.7747862425  0.2435730944  0.8011542666  0.343155766  -0.6091592581  -0.3093581909  -0.3446424728  -0.1860752773  -0.4163819443  -0.6336083058  0.7641081337  -0.4112580017  -0.8234841915  0.1845683194  0.4291770641  -0.7959243273  -0.2650864686  0.449371034  -0.203724703  0.6074620459  0.2253373638  -0.6009791836  -0.9861692137  0.1804598471  0.1922068008  -0.9246806119  0.6522353256  -0.2222336438  0.7990992685  -0.9092588527  -0.9414539684  0.9236803664  0.0148272357  -0.1772637652  0.05628269894  -0.08566629406  -0.6007759525  0.7041888058  0.4769729119  0.6532997034  -0.5427364139  -0.5772239915  0.5491494803  0.9278330427  0.2263117816  -0.290121617  0.7363179158  0.8949343019  -0.02399176716  0.5629439653  -0.5493977074  -0.8596191107  -0.7992328333  0.4388809483  0.6354737076  0.3641705918  0.9951120218  0.412591228  -0.75696169  0.9514620339  -0.3618197699  0.06038199928  0  0  0  0
```

As far as I've gotten in one approach is using awk to index the right columns.. (just printing them right now) but I can only get this to work if I call $1 (i.e., the numeric index of the first outlier column)...

```
awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' $bvec_file
```

If I try to refer to the value in $outlier, it doesn't work. Instead, this prints the entire contents of $bvec_file

```
while read outlier; do
    
    # Remove current outlier vol from eddy unwarped DWI data
    rm $DWI_path/$1/vol000*"$outlier".nii.gz;
    
    # Remove outlier #'s from bvec file 
    awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' $bvec_file

done < $outlier_file
```

I am completely stuck on how to get this done. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you work with text files, focus your efforts on learning `awk`. It is truly the swiss-army-knife of text processing and orders of magnitude faster than `while read...` for large files. The [GNU awk Users Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) is a great reference. It takes a while to figure out where all the pieces are hidden, but well worth the time to make friends with it. All aspects of scripting are important, but time spent learning `awk` (and `sed`) will pay significant dividends quickly.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't run into many instances before where I've needed to work with text files, so I am new to it. I definitely will take your advice to read up on awk / sed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the outliers from bvec_file after the loop and only delete the ones where the associated file was successfully removed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
while IFS= read -r outlier; do
    
    # Remove current outlier vol from eddy unwarped DWI data
    rm "$DWI_path/$1"/vol000*"$outlier".nii.gz &&
    echo "$outlier"

done < "$outlier_file" |
awk '
    NR==FNR { os[$0]; next }
    {
        for (o in os) {
            $o=""
        }
        $0=$0; $1=$1
    }
1' - "$bvec_file" > "$tmp" &&
mv "$tmp" "$bvec_file"
```

Or to delete the outliers one at a time as the files are removed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1
while IFS= read -r outlier; do
    
    # Remove current outlier vol from eddy unwarped DWI data
    rm "$DWI_path/$1"/vol000*"$outlier".nii.gz &&
    
    # Remove outlier #'s from bvec file 
    awk -v o="$outlier" '{$o=""; $0=$0; $1=$1} 1' "$bvec_file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv "$tmp" "$bvec_file"

done < <(sort -rnu "$outlier_file")
```

Always quote your shell variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, and the `&&` at the end of each line is to ensure the next command only runs if the previous commands succeeded.

The magical incantation in the awk script does the following - lets say your input is `a b c` and the outlier field is field number 2, `b`:

```
$ echo 'a b c'
a b c
$
$ echo 'a b c' | awk -v o=2 '{$o=""; print NF ":", $0}'
3: a  c
$
$ echo 'a b c' | awk -v o=2 '{$o=""; $0=$0; print NF ":", $0}'
2: a  c
$
$ echo 'a b c' | awk -v o=2 '{$o=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print NF ":", $0}'
2: a c
```

The `o=""` sets the field value to null, the `$0=$0` forces awk to resplit `$0` into fields so it effectively deletes field 2 (as opposed to the previous step which set it to null but it still existed as such), and the `$1=$1` recombines `$0` from it's fields replacing every `FS` (any contiguous chain of white space chars including the 2 blanks now between `a` and `c`) with `OFS` (a single blank char).

Comment: Thank you SO much for the helpful explanation, code, & other tips. I am still wrapping my head around the magical awk command & playing with it. 

One question, however, as of right now: with the above code, it is deleting the first outlier column correctly (e.g., deleting col 1). Then, for the second outlier, instead of deleting the original column 7, it is deleting the original column 8 (aka the 'new' column 7, once you've deleted column 1). Do you have a suggestion to alleviate this so that it deletes based on the original column indices? 

Thank you again so much for your help!!

Comment: In particular, I am confused about which direction to go to get awk to remove all of the outliers at one time: 
1) if I put the awk command as-is outside of the loop, `$outlier` is nothing so it can 't use that to index the columns to remove 

2) if I pipe all of the outliers to a variable inside the while loop then call awk outside the loop, it only removes the first outlier column 
`outlier_list+=$outlier
awk -v o="$outlier_list" '{$o=""; $0=$0; $1=$1} 1' "$bvec_file" > "$tmp"

Comment: & then changing the second option to something like `awk -v o="${outlier_list[@]}" '{$o=""; $0=$0; $1=$1} 1' "$bvec_file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$bvec_file_corr"' `outside of the while loop also does not work. It again removes only the 1st column .

Comment: Ah, right, the column numbers shift as one is deleted, You can fix that by changing `< "$outlier_file"` to `< <(sort -rnu "$outlier_file")` so the removals happen from the highest column number to the lowest, i.e. right to left in the bvec_file. I updated my answer to show that and I added an option to update bvec_file after the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! Both of these work perfectly! Last question: I realized that the MRI volume indexing (and the outlier.txt file) starts counting at 0, whereas this is starting to count at 1. So "1" in the outlier.txt file actually means that column "2" in "$bvec_file" should be removed. Adding something like ` awk -v o=$( "$outlier" + 1) ` does not work. (The alternative could be using a separate outlier.txt file that starts counting at 0 not 1 for "$bvec_file", but I wasn't sure if there was a simpler solution.)

Comment: Just change every `$o` to `$(o+1)` in the awk script. FYI the bash syntax for what you were considering would have been `awk -v o="(( outlier + 1))"`